# Docker image cannot be built

Tags: docker, centos, docker-machine, docker-image

Hello I created a base image; however, whenever I run the docker build ., I don't see the successfully built

**My docker file**

```
FROM centos:7

ARG user=john
ARG home=/home/$user

RUN yum update -y
RUN yum install openssh-server -y
RUN yum install openssh-clients -y

RUN useradd -d $home -p "$(openssl passwd $user)" $user

CMD ["hostnamectl"]
```

I tried running but, I get this

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/) to see the details about images on your system.

Comment: oh thank you i have seen my id but unfortunately, i still can't run it

A:\test-project>docker run  b711332ff51f
Failed to create bus connection: No such file or directory

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/1190804

Comment: Also, if you can update the post with the `docker images` output.

Comment: Hello this is the output

Comment: Hello this is the output

test/project               latest    b711332ff51f   2 hours ago         734MB

I can finally run it by docker run -it test/project /bin/bash


I can finally go inside the image but when I run command like systemctl status sshd
I get Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted

or when i run firewall-cmd, Error: DBUS_ERROR: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239145/discussion-between-ana-marie-de-vera-and-kiner-shah).

Answer (score 0):

Your container includes `systemd` which will not run under this circumstances.

Comment: oh does that mean it will prevent me running certain commands also like firewall-cmd

Comment: Correct. you can't run a container like a VM.

Comment: are there any images that does not have systemd?

Comment: We need to follow the 1 question 1 answer rule. Can you mark the answer as it explained your issue. Then open a new question - be very specific about what you expect the container to do.  Happy to take it from there.